# jQuery ui autocomplete get selected item in other function

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, autocomplete

I have a problem with jQuery autocomplete, I try to get the value of the input but I get the label but no the value.

```
  var listeClients = [{"value":1,"label":"Orange"},{"value":2,"label":"Blue"}];
  $( "#site_client_first" ).autocomplete({
     source: listeClients,
     select: function (event, ui) {
         $("#site_client_first").val(ui.item.label);
         return false;
  }
```

And for get the value I use :

```
$("#site_client_first").val();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fyz8vL3a/

How to get the value ?

Thanks by advance =)

Comment: Your code should work as expected. `.val()` is the proper way of returning the value. Can you reproduce the problem in https://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: I try this but it not work ... https://jsfiddle.net/cabri89/66fym60o/

Comment: @NicolasCabridens: If you set the "Load Type" option to "No wrap in `<head>`" in JSFiddle, everything works: https://jsfiddle.net/e2pbLggs/1/

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker Thanks. It my first time with JsFiddle ^^ How I get the value and no the label ?

Answer (score 0):

In the select event of autocomplete, you are setting the label as value property of element #site_client_first i.e. here $("#site_client_first").val(ui.item.label). Hence when you try to set the span's innerHTML by assigning $("#site_client_first").val(), you will always get the label and not your item.value.

Try the code below. I have added an attribute 'itemValue' to $("#site_client_first"). This will hold your item's value and $("#site_client_first").val() will hold the item's label.

And when setting up the span innerhtml, you assign $("#site_client_first").attr("itemValue") which is your item's value.

```
<input class="form-control" name="site[client]" id="site_client_first"  itemValue="100" />
```

Make change to the above line in your HTML change.
Your final html is as belows:

```
<input class="form-control" name="site[client]" id="site_client_first"  itemValue="100" />
<button onclick="getValue()">Get</button>
<span id="svalue"></span>
```

Your script goes here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var listeClients = [{ "value": 1, "label": "Orange"}, {
"value": 2,
"label": "Blue"
}];

$("#site_client_first").autocomplete({
source: listeClients,
select: function(event, ui) {
  $("#site_client_first").val(ui.item.label);
   $("#site_client_first").attr("itemValue", ui.item.value);
  return false;
}
});

})

var getValue = function() {
document.getElementById("value").innerHTML = $("#site_client_first").attr("itemValue");
}

function getValue() {
document.getElementById("value").innerHTML = $("#site_client_first").attr("itemValue");
}
```

Comment: Like @Alexandru Severin it work. It a good solution, thanks a lot for your explain ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying to use an `input` element as a [select](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) element.

Unlike for a `select`, the value for an `input` is simply what is written in it.

The default behavior of the `autocomplete` plugin is to display the `labels` of given `source` as suggestions, and when you select one them it sets the corresponding `value` in the `input`. You are overriding this functionality in the code below, by setting the `label` as `value` of the `input`:

```
select: function (event, ui) {
     $("#site_client_first").val(ui.item.label);
     return false;
}
```

If you were to remove the piece of code above, you would notice that the `value` field will be written in the `input` element upon selection of an option.

**Solution 1**

I recommend replacing your `input` element with a `select` one. Which I think better suits your needs. If you need to search through the options you may want to use a plugin like [chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) or [select2](https://select2.github.io/).

**Solution 2**

If you're keen on using an `input` with `autocomplete`, set the value as an extra attribute in the `select` callback

```
select: function (event, ui) {
    $("#site_client_first").val(ui.item.label); // what the user sees
    $("#site_client_first").attr('data-realValue', ui.item.value); // value is hidden
    return false;
}
```

You can retrieve the value using

```
$("#site_client_first").attr('data-realValue');
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/fyz8vL3a/1/

Comment: Nice it work. It a good solution, thanks a lot for your explain ;)